# Disable IPv6 in Docker containers on K8s created by Kops on AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, kubernetes, ipv6, kops

I'm running k8s 1.9.3 created with Kops on AWS. All my containers get ipv6 address (in addition to ipv4). The ipv6 localhost in the /etc/hosts seems to break my application's framework.

I'm looking for a reliable way to disable ipv6 inside the containers.

So far tried:

- Disabled the ipv6 on the hosts (using the asg launch configuration) - didn't affect the containers who still get ipv6.
- Tried to set Dcoker's `--ipv6: false` flag (using the asg launch configuration) - from some reason it didn't take and the `dockerd` starts without this flag.

If anyone has any experience with this issue any advise will be appreciated.

Best,

Comment: You can't fix your application? This is a serious bug and should be resolved ASAP. IPv6 isn't going away and you'll have to have it sooner or later.

Comment: Rework of the app is in progress but I'm trying to find a mitigation in the meanwhile.

Comment: You didn't say what the problem was, so it's impossible to say what a good mitigation would be.